# When trying to feed in variable sequences to keras LSTMs ValueError: Error when checking input?

Tags: numpy, keras, lstm

My model:

`model = Sequential()`

`model.add( LSTM(25, batch_input_shape = (None, None, 19), return_sequences = True ) )`

`model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'tanh'))`

`model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer ='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])`

> some example of input data shape:

input_list[0].shape = (7,19)

input_list[1].shape = (8,19)

input_list[2].shape = (17,19)

> some example of output data shape:

output_list[0].shape = (7,4)

output_list[1].shape = (8,4)

output_list[2].shape = (17,4)

- input_list.shape = (233,)
- output_list.shape = (233,)

> error while:

`d_loss = model.fit(input_list,output_list,validation_split=0.33,nb_epoch=100,verbose=1,shuffle=True, batch_size = 1)`

error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (233, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase the dimensions, by np.expand_dims(x, axis= 0). It will become three dimensional.